# Como consumir uma API GraphQL (https://api.loggi.com)

Tags: asp.net, api, graphql

Gostaria de entender conhecer e saber opiniões para aplicar em um projeto com urgência...
Atualmente possuo um site de compras e preciso utilizar a API da empresa loggi que é uma empresa de distribuição o link da api é https://api.loggi.com,
já utilizei os metodos antigos deles para consulta do preço do cep mas para efetuar pesquisas mais robustas como Login, acompanhamento de pedido, etc... eles dizem para que eu use o método novo que é com GraphQL, já criei um projeto em node.js utilizando local simples como Hello World, mas não entendo como configura-lo para rodar por exemplo o script abaixo que é para localizar as cidades cadastradas

```
$ curl -v 'https://staging.loggi.com/graphql?' \
>     -H 'content-type: application/json' \
>     -H 'authorization: ApiKey a-valid-username@domain.com:a-valid-api-key' \
>     --compressed \
>     --data-binary '{"query":"query { allCities { edges { node { pk name slug } } } }"}'
>
> POST /graphql? HTTP/1.1
> Host: staging.loggi.com
> content-type: application/json
> ApiKey a-valid-username@domain.com:a-valid-api-key
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
<
{"data":{"allCities":{"edges":[{"node":{"pk":4,"name":"Curitiba","slug":"ct"}},{"node":{"pk":1,"name":"S\u00e3o Paulo","slug":"sp"}},{"node":{"pk":2,"name":"Rio de Janeiro","slug":"rj"}},{"node":{"pk":3,"name":"Belo Horizonte","slug":"bh"}},{"node":{"pk":5,"name":"Porto Alegre","slug":"pa"}}]}}}
```

Alguém já utilizou essa API ou alguma API semelhante ? (Não sei se CURL seria uma requisição js ou do próprio GraphQL)

Obs: Meu site está feito em Asp.net WebForms e desculpem a ignorancia pela falta de conhecimento, fiz pesquisas e mais pesquisas sobre GraphQL e entendi apenas que é uma maneira facilitada de ler uma API. Pelo que eu pesquisei também o CURL seria equivalente ao WebRequest no c#, estou certo?

Método antigo que consegui utilizar que seria com a API RestFul deles e foi apenas uma requisição em JSON, não precisava de login,apikey e nenhuma credencial:

```
 {
        "transport_type": 1,
        "city": 1,
        "addresses": [
            {
                "by": "cep",
                "query": {
                    "cep": "01426000",
                    "number": 300
                }
            },
            {
                "by": "address",
                "query": {
                    "category": "Rua",
                    "address": "Oscar Freire",
                    "number": 100
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Mas se você consegue acessar a api via GraphQL, você consegue também no asp.net.

Comment: @CassioAlves a questão é essa, eu não consigo acessar a API.

Comment: Eu acessei a Api, e você precisa criar um login no site através deste link: https://www.loggi.com/contas/criar/ e apos isto, você deve acessar este link: https://www.loggi.com/contas/haxor/ para que a sua Key seja gerada, dai basta você usar a API normalmente em C#.

Comment: Olá Para poder consumir uma API GraphQL voce necessita de um client para poder fazer o middleware entre o GraphQL e sua aplicação segue abaixo alguns: - Apollo Client: https://apollographql.com/
- Relay: https://facebook.github.io/relay/